# Where to find specs on how javascript handles duplicate object key?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I know that in the example below

```js
var test = { a: 'a', a: 'b' };

console.log(test);
```

It will output

```
{
  "a": "b"
}
```

Now, I want to know where are the specs on how javascript handles duplicate object keys upon creation.
I tried in ECMA but couldn't exactly pinpoint where.

The closest thing I got is the parse as in the link below

[JSON Parse](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.12.2)

Any help would be great!

Comment: If you're only talking about object literals, then perhaps [section 12.2.6 is what you're after](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-object-initializer). It only deals with object literals (or "initializer" according to the spec). That's [section 11.1.5 in the ES5 spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.5) if you're more interested in that. Confusingly, the spelling of "initialiser" is different between the two  version - ES5 uses the British English spelling with **s**, while the current ES spec uses the American English spelling with **z**.

Comment: Maybe you might also want to look [here](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-createdataproperty), specifically at the _note_ part.

Comment: I think this is the same as assignment，first``test['a'] = 'a'``,then ``test['a'] = 'b'``